Geometry search by frustum using PostGIS 3.3.4
I have a table, that represents model elements:
create table bim_geometry (
 id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
 name VARCHAR(64),
 geom geometry(POLYHEDRALSURFACEZ, 0)
)

I want to get elements that fit completely or partially into the camera's frustum.
For example, I created a frustum of 5 coordinates,
which simulates a camera:

As shown in the example, the elements of the model are included in the volume of the cone.
WITH f (frustum) as (
    select st_geomfromtext(
        'POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z ( 
    ((
        -0.006203383207321167 0.01904459297657013 0.028260480612516403,
        -0.8183298707008362 -0.23640798032283783 1.9843486547470093,
        -0.11939674615859985 -0.23640809953212738 2.1518564224243164,
        -0.006203383207321167 0.01904459297657013 0.028260480612516403
    )),((
        -0.006203383207321167 0.01904459297657013 0.028260480612516403,
        -0.8183298707008362 -0.23640798032283783 1.9843486547470093,
        -0.7926796674728394 -0.6785006523132324 1.8773213624954224,
        -0.006203383207321167 0.01904459297657013 0.028260480612516403
    )),((
        -0.006203383207321167 0.01904459297657013 0.028260480612516403,
        -0.11939674615859985 -0.23640809953212738 2.1518564224243164,
        -0.09374647587537766 -0.6785009503364563 2.0448291301727295,
        -0.006203383207321167 0.01904459297657013 0.028260480612516403
    )),((
        -0.006203383207321167 0.01904459297657013 0.028260480612516403,
        -0.09374647587537766 -0.6785009503364563 2.0448291301727295,
        -0.7926796674728394 -0.6785006523132324 1.8773213624954224,
        -0.006203383207321167 0.01904459297657013 0.028260480612516403
    )),((
        -0.09374647587537766 -0.6785009503364563 2.0448291301727295,
        -0.11939674615859985 -0.23640809953212738 2.1518564224243164,
        -0.8183298707008362 -0.23640798032283783 1.9843486547470093,
        -0.09374647587537766 -0.6785009503364563 2.0448291301727295
    )),((
        -0.8183298707008362 -0.23640798032283783 1.9843486547470093,
        -0.7926796674728394 -0.6785006523132324 1.8773213624954224,
        -0.09374647587537766 -0.6785009503364563 2.0448291301727295,
        -0.8183298707008362 -0.23640798032283783 1.9843486547470093
    ))
)')::geometry)
SELECT * from bim_geometry, f where ST_3dintersects(geom, f.frustum)

My query returns all elements that touch the faces of frustum, but I can't get those elements that are completely in frustum.
I'd like to find geometry that either completely encloses or partially intersects the frustum.
Query to add elements:
insert into bim_geometry (geom, name) values (
'POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z( 
((-0.02483932487666607 0 0.10456433892250061, -0.0274555254727602 0.0031951998826116323 0.10456433892250061, -0.02483932487666607 0.0031951998826116323 0.10456433892250061, -0.02483932487666607 0 0.10456433892250061)),((-0.0274555254727602 0.0031951998826116323 0.10456433892250061, -0.02483932487666607 0 0.10456433892250061, -0.0274555254727602 0 0.10456433892250061, -0.0274555254727602 0.0031951998826116323 0.10456433892250061)),((-0.0274555254727602 0 0.10456433892250061, -0.0274555254727602 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274, -0.0274555254727602 0.0031951998826116323 0.10456433892250061, -0.0274555254727602 0 0.10456433892250061)),((-0.0274555254727602 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274, -0.0274555254727602 0 0.10456433892250061, -0.0274555254727602 0 0.10441433638334274, -0.0274555254727602 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274)),((-0.0274555254727602 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274, -0.02483932487666607 0 0.10441433638334274, -0.02483932487666607 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274, -0.0274555254727602 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274)),((-0.02483932487666607 0 0.10441433638334274, -0.0274555254727602 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274, -0.0274555254727602 0 0.10441433638334274, -0.02483932487666607 0 0.10441433638334274)),((-0.02483932487666607 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274, -0.02483932487666607 0 0.10456433892250061, -0.02483932487666607 0.0031951998826116323 0.10456433892250061, -0.02483932487666607 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274)),((-0.02483932487666607 0 0.10456433892250061, -0.02483932487666607 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274, -0.02483932487666607 0 0.10441433638334274, -0.02483932487666607 0 0.10456433892250061)),((-0.02483932487666607 0 0.10441433638334274, -0.0274555254727602 0 0.10456433892250061, -0.02483932487666607 0 0.10456433892250061, -0.02483932487666607 0 0.10441433638334274)),((-0.0274555254727602 0 0.10456433892250061, -0.02483932487666607 0 0.10441433638334274, -0.0274555254727602 0 0.10441433638334274, -0.0274555254727602 0 0.10456433892250061)),((-0.0274555254727602 0.0031951998826116323 0.10456433892250061, -0.02483932487666607 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274, -0.02483932487666607 0.0031951998826116323 0.10456433892250061, -0.0274555254727602 0.0031951998826116323 0.10456433892250061)),((-0.02483932487666607 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274, -0.0274555254727602 0.0031951998826116323 0.10456433892250061, -0.0274555254727602 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274, -0.02483932487666607 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274))
)',
    'test2'
)

insert into bim_geometry (geom, name) values (
'POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z( 
((-0.021918324753642082 0 0.10456433892250061, -0.024534525349736214 0.0031951998826116323 0.10456433892250061, -0.021918324753642082 0.0031951998826116323 0.10456433892250061, -0.021918324753642082 0 0.10456433892250061)),((-0.024534525349736214 0.0031951998826116323 0.10456433892250061, -0.021918324753642082 0 0.10456433892250061, -0.024534525349736214 0 0.10456433892250061, -0.024534525349736214 0.0031951998826116323 0.10456433892250061)),((-0.024534525349736214 0 0.10456433892250061, -0.024534525349736214 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274, -0.024534525349736214 0.0031951998826116323 0.10456433892250061, -0.024534525349736214 0 0.10456433892250061)),((-0.024534525349736214 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274, -0.024534525349736214 0 0.10456433892250061, -0.024534525349736214 0 0.10441433638334274, -0.024534525349736214 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274)),((-0.024534525349736214 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274, -0.021918324753642082 0 0.10441433638334274, -0.021918324753642082 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274, -0.024534525349736214 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274)),((-0.021918324753642082 0 0.10441433638334274, -0.024534525349736214 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274, -0.024534525349736214 0 0.10441433638334274, -0.021918324753642082 0 0.10441433638334274)),((-0.021918324753642082 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274, -0.021918324753642082 0 0.10456433892250061, -0.021918324753642082 0.0031951998826116323 0.10456433892250061, -0.021918324753642082 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274)),((-0.021918324753642082 0 0.10456433892250061, -0.021918324753642082 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274, -0.021918324753642082 0 0.10441433638334274, -0.021918324753642082 0 0.10456433892250061)),((-0.021918324753642082 0 0.10441433638334274, -0.024534525349736214 0 0.10456433892250061, -0.021918324753642082 0 0.10456433892250061, -0.021918324753642082 0 0.10441433638334274)),((-0.024534525349736214 0 0.10456433892250061, -0.021918324753642082 0 0.10441433638334274, -0.024534525349736214 0 0.10441433638334274, -0.024534525349736214 0 0.10456433892250061)),((-0.024534525349736214 0.0031951998826116323 0.10456433892250061, -0.021918324753642082 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274, -0.021918324753642082 0.0031951998826116323 0.10456433892250061, -0.024534525349736214 0.0031951998826116323 0.10456433892250061)),((-0.021918324753642082 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274, -0.024534525349736214 0.0031951998826116323 0.10456433892250061, -0.024534525349736214 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274, -0.021918324753642082 0.0031951998826116323 0.10441433638334274))
)',
    'test1'
)


Don't try if you are not willing to code in the respective functionality yourself - PostGIS does not attempt to support geometric operations on what is called a volume in the OGC context. Frustrum culling is most efficiently done on a GPU and/or in the programming language of your choice, e.g. and for quick setups ScyPy has amazing matrix abstraction, THREE.js can be run in Node.
